# ComboBox with grouping and custom group headers

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I would like to create a grouped `ComboBox` with a group header which is bound to not only the group's name, but other properties of the values by which the 'ItemsSource' of the `ComboBox` is grouped as well.

This is the `CollectionViewSource` which is used as the `ComboBox`es `ItemsSource`:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="Tools" Source="{Binding AvailableTools}">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Toolbox" />
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

The property by which I group, is not a string property, but an object of a custom type. The `CollectionViewSource` obviously creates groups and gives each group the name of `[object by which is group].ToString()`, yielding the type name of the property `Toolbox` in my example.

Here's the combo:

```
<ComboBox 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTool, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Margin="10,0,0,0"
    Width="40" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Tools}}">
    <ComboBox .GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="CollectionViewGroup">
                    <Grid Background="{StaticResource LighterBackgroundBrush}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ComboBox .GroupStyle>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="viewModels1:ToolSelectionItem">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Tool.ToolIcon}" Width="16" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ToolName}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>        
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

In the header template, I can bind to the groups name but nothing else. What I would like to achieve, is a binding to the object by which a group was created and not just it's `ToString()` result. I.e. the values of the `Toolbox` property by which I group contain an `Icon` property of type `BitmapImage` which I would like to bind to an Image inside the header template to display this icon in the group header. **Can this be done at all and if so, how?**

The issue is a bit difficult to explain, please ask, if I am not being clear enough...